# Alert message before Java Applet, cause Browser no response

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I facing a problem on put an alert message "Please accept the JAVA applet." before the page loading the java applet cause The browser just not responding.
I suspend the java applet loading and ask for user permission to accept it.

```
<Html>
  <Head>
    <Title>Java Example</Title>
  </Head>
<script>
  alert("Please accept the JAVA applet.");
</script>
  <Body>
    This is my page<br>
    Below you see an applet<br>
    <br>
    <Applet Code="MyApplet.class" width=200 Height=100>
    </Applet>
  </Body>
</Html>
```

Comment: Use only lowercased letters in HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like that:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Java Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         This is my page<br/>
         Below you see an applet<br/>
         <script>
              var result = confirm("Please accept the JAVA applet.");
              if(result == true) {
                   document.write("<applet code='MyApplet.class' style='width:200px;height:100px;'>
                   </applet>");
              }
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could you please also write HTML code according to the standards.

EDIT:
Well, in that case please use "alert" function instead of "confirm". Your script should look like:

```
<script>
    alert("Please accept the JAVA applet.");
    document.write("<applet code='MyApplet.class' style='width:200px;height:100px;'>
               </applet>");          
</script>
```

If my answer have met your requirements please mark it.

Comment: Thank for the response.
But the Confirm will asked user to click OK or Cancel.
For this "Please accept the JAVA applet.", it should be only OK button.
Any other better solution for this?

Comment: Thank you for the solution.
Sorry to say that, I tried but the browser still not responding..